# BreezeJS central error handler and auto retry

Tags: javascript, breeze

Is there a way to for Breeze JS to auto retry in the case of a communications failure? Ideally I want to add a central event handler where based in the response, for example 401 I could prompt the user to re-login and then retry the request, or if its general connection problem give the user the option to Retry or Cancel?

I could add code at each request location to handle this, but that would be a lot of work, ideally this needs to be in a central location.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the retry logic in a **[request interceptor](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/controlling-ajax)**.

From the breeze docs:

> Stock Breeze AJAX adapters offer an extension point, the requestInterceptor. This interceptor gives the developer one last look at each request before the adapter calls the actual AJAX component.
>   The interceptor takes a single parameter, the requestInfo, and returns
>   nothing.

```
var requestInfo = {
        adapter: this,      // this AJAX adapter
        config: ...,        // the configuration object passed to the wrapped AJAX component
        dsaConfig: config,  // the config arg from the calling Breeze DataServiceAdapter
        success: successFn, // adapter's success callback
        error: errorFn      // adapter's error callback
}
```

Your request interceptor could wrap the `error` callback and add retry logic and 401 handling.

If you're using breeze with jQuery you could do this at a lower level, using jQuery's [ajax prefilter](https://www.google.com/#q=ajax+prefilter+retry).

Comment: And I think you can also us $http interceptors for this purpose if you're using Angular. Here's one implementation of that approach: https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth (note: I haven't tried it myself). This way you don't have to involve Breeze at all.